# Doubly exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

Miklos Bona, Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics, Rudin, 2007, Section 3.5 , page 173 gives the definition and one example of a doubly exponential generating function.  The author states in the introduction to this section that these are used "in one of the later chapters".  Does anyone know exactly where else in this book these functions are discussed.  Does anyone have any other references that I could find on-line to give myself an introduction to this type of generating function.

Comment: Did you try the index?

Comment: @J.G.: It has only a reference to p. 173, and I do not recall seeing any other use of them in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular example in Bona is the
[OEIS sequence A061573](https://oeis.org/A061573). See [OEIS sequence A000275](https://oies.org/A000275)
for another example which is
$$ 1/J_0(\sqrt{4x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!^2}. $$
There are other examples in the OEIS. In general, when you have a
[Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)
 power series there can be $\,n!^2\,$
in the denominator of the terms. For example,
$$ {}_2F_1(a,b;1;x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n(b)_n}
{n!^2}x^n. $$

Comment: OK, Thank you!.  Do you know where in Bona this particular example is discussed?

Comment: I do not have a copy of Bona. He may have been mistaken in his statement. You can find discussions on Doubly-Exponential g.f. by doing a web search. For example, the book by Stanley, _Enumerative Combinatorics_.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I did find finally find it on page 487, section 9.3 , Magic Squares.